# update cancel on gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, edit

I am trying to update a gridview on asp.net using a stored procedure but it always resets to the original values. What am I doing wrong?

edit: all page code added now

```
  protected void page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MembershipUser UserName;
        try
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // Set theme in preInit event
                UserName = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
                Session["UserName"] = UserName;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message;


        }


    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userLabel.Text = Session["UserName"].ToString();

        SqlDataReader myDataReader = default(SqlDataReader);

        SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RescueAnimalsIrelandConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_EditRescueDetails", MyConnection);

        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userLabel.Text.Trim());

        }

        try
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            MyConnection.Open();


            myDataReader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            // myDataReader.Read();


            GridViewED.DataSource = myDataReader;
            GridViewED.DataBind();

            if (GridViewED.Rows.Count >= 1)
            {

                GridViewED.Visible = true;
                lblMsg.Visible = false;

            }
            else if (GridViewED.Rows.Count < 1)
            {
                GridViewED.Visible = false;

                lblMsg.Text = "Your search criteria returned no results.";
                lblMsg.Visible = true;
            }





            MyConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException SQLexc)
        {
            Response.Write("Read Failed : " + SQLexc.ToString());
        }
    }
    //to edit grid view
    protected void GridViewED_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewED.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    }


 protected void GridViewED_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RescueAnimalsIrelandConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_UpdateRescueDetails", MyConnection);

        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userLabel.Text.Trim());

            command.Parameters.Add("@PostalAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ((TextBox)GridViewED.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text;

            command.Parameters.Add("@TelephoneNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ((TextBox)GridViewED.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;

            command.Parameters.Add("@Website", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ((TextBox)GridViewED.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;

            command.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ((TextBox)GridViewED.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;

        }


        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        MyConnection.Open();

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();


        MyConnection.Close();


        GridViewED.EditIndex = -1;



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the code loading the grid is being invoked upon postback, which is causing the data to be pulled from the database when you don't want it to.

Yes - I think you want the code to only load if it is not a postback.  You can use the Page.IsPostBack property for this.

Something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userLabel.Text = Session["UserName"].ToString();

    if (!IsPostBack) {

    SqlDataReader myDataReader = default(SqlDataReader);

    SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RescueAnimalsIrelandConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_EditRescueDetails", MyConnection);

    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userLabel.Text.Trim());

    }

    try
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        MyConnection.Open();


        myDataReader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        // myDataReader.Read();


        GridViewED.DataSource = myDataReader;
        GridViewED.DataBind();

        if (GridViewED.Rows.Count >= 1)
        {

            GridViewED.Visible = true;
            lblMsg.Visible = false;

        }
        else if (GridViewED.Rows.Count < 1)
        {
            GridViewED.Visible = false;

            lblMsg.Text = "Your search criteria returned no results.";
            lblMsg.Visible = true;
        }





        MyConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (SqlException SQLexc)
    {
        Response.Write("Read Failed : " + SQLexc.ToString());
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't bind your data in the Page_Load event.  Create a separate method that does it, then in the Page Load, if !IsPostback, call it.

The reason to perform the databinding is it's own method is because you'll need to call it if you're paging through the dataset, deleting, updating, etc, after you perform the task.  A call to a method is better than many instances of the same, repetitive, databinding code.